# IR Booster API for Java?

Tags: java, android, api

is there a way or an API to code an IR booster in Java?
We want to develop an app (we are in grade 11, south africa) that is able to control the tv remote/channel using an android tablet.

so my question: is there already a built API for an IR Booster in Java?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the Android SDK regarding IR. IR capabilities are provided by device manufacturers, and only on a few devices. Please contact your device manufacturer to inquire about device-specific SDKs related to IR.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a previous answer, there is no IR API in the Android SDK.  So you have to look for the venders.

- For HTC, the [HTC OpenSens SDK](http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk) provides an API.
- For Samsung, as far as I know, they don't provide an API.  However, there is this [irDude](https://github.com/rngtng/IrDude) application on GitHub that could be used as a starting point. It was developped for the Galaxy Note, but who knows, it may also work with other Samsung devices.